# Hacking NodeJS based APIs: How to use the Query.skip() property correctly?

Tags: mongoose

I am making a restful API where there is a pagination feature in the API,
the API consumer of the API can provide the `?page=1&limit=7` as an example.

- the algorithm (which i'm not sure about btw) to determine the `skip()` value is

  **const skip = page * limit**
- the skip variable is used here:

  **theCarsModel.skip(Math.abs(skip))**
- I'm using Math.abs to force the user input to be a positive number, if a string given, it will be NaN, which seems to be okay and working

the problem I've seen is:

1. the hacker of the API may provide an infinity value to the page or the limit, this causes mongoose to fail and show the following error, but first here is how to cause this error: the hacker will send this http query

`http://example.com?page=1&limit=1e10000`

- 1e10000 basically means infinity

```js
    {
        "status": "Error",
        "data": {
            "ok": 0,
            "code": 2,
            "codeName": "BadValue",
            "name": "MongoError"
        },
        "message": "Skip value must be non-negative, but received: -9223372036854775808"
    }
```

1. How to use the skip method correctly in my case
2. are there any hidden cases where this could cause an error, I've tried 1e10000, but if there are anything I don't know please write in the answers
3. what if there are other strings that could evaluate to some values, I'm not very familiar with this thing in JavaScript, so if JavaScript is evaluating some strings to real data types, then what if a hacker used a string that can evaluate to binary and JavaScript evaluated that string to some malicious code, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should always sanitize and validate the data before using them in your database queries. In this case, you need create an middleware(assuming that you use express as your server) to validate your `limit` parameter.

Using `Math.abs` alone is not sufficient in your case. You need to add more validations.

**Example :**

Router.js :

```js
router.get('/resource/:page/:limit',validateRequest,Controller.handleRequest);
```

validateRequest.js :

```js
module.exports = (req,res,next) =>{

  const {page,limit} = req.params;

  if(!page || !limit) return Error;

//Example validations

  if(isNaN(parseInt(limit))) return Error;

  if(parseInt(limit) > MAX || parseInt(limit) < MIN) return Error;

  next();

}
```

This code is just to give you an overview. You can follow your style and add your own validations as per your system requirement.